# How to Restart ADB server

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb, genymotion

I use `genymotion` as emulator. I restarted eclipse and the `adb` is correctly located but the application does not start.

Here is the error:

```
[2014-12-13 14:57:52 - Serbay] ------------------------------    
[2014-12-13 14:57:52 - Serbay] Android Launch! 
[2014-12-13 14:57:52 - Serbay] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has    occured. 
[2014-12-13 14:57:52 - Serbay] You must restart adb and    Eclipse. 
[2014-12-13 14:57:52 - Serbay] Please ensure that adb is    correctly located at    'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' and    can be executed.
```

Answer (score 6):

Do it in the command prompt

- **`adb kill-server`**
- **`adb start-server`**

Re-start your IDE

Type  "**`where adb.exe`**" & see the output (Should be 'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe')

Comment: Can you explain little more specific? I am new at android

Comment: I would also add ending the adb.exe from the **Task Manager** too first, and after run the commands you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

go to DDMS and right side it will display 12 icons there select reset adb will be there,then reset adb it will work may be